# Prevent certain folder in public folder from being removed capistrano rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have an app that users upload images and they are stored, via CarrierWave, to the public folder, in a folder named uploads/images/.

I just noticed that since my most recent deploy, the uploads (and images) folder(s) is no longer there.

Could it be removing the folder and files on the production server when I deploy with Capistrano?

How can I tell it to keep the same public/uploads folder through all deploys?

Thanks Stack!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend making a capistrano task that creates a symlink to the shared folder. The symlink will act as a link to the directory, so all your upload storage/retrieval code will work as normal.

Capistrano task example:

```
before "deploy:restart", :symlink_directories
task :symlink_directories do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
end
```

Comment: Could you recommend a good walk through/example of doing this? I'm new to Rails and Capistrano, so I'm still learning.

Comment: Just put the above task in your deploy.rb and change the paths to be appropriate for your application

Comment: So I put the task in my deploy.rb, however, when I navigate to the public/uploads folder for the current release it says it can't resolve symlink "uploads".

I don't actually have a "public/uploads" in my shared folder. Should I manually create that?

Comment: Just put an `uploads` folder in your shared folder, no need for the `public` directory in shared. You should manually create it, but after it is created, you shouldn't need to do it again.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to update this answer for those looking to do the same with Capistrano v3.9.1

In your deploy.rb file, you can add the following

```
set :linked_dirs,  %w{public/uploads/}
```

As in the answer above, this symlinks directories into the release during deployment.

Ideal for directories such as upload where we do not want to overwrite the contents.

For a full list of variables that you can "set" see the [capistrano docs here.](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/)

Comment: Your answer should include some explanation as well as required code.

Comment: @svgrafov I have provided a better explanation and linked to the source. Also note, required code is already set. No pun intended.

Comment: "Also note, required code is already set"
There must be some misunderstanding, because I meant that "You have a source code, then why not add some explanation?"